# How can I avoid redundancy while declaring new class attributes in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

In my code, every time I need a new object attribute for my class, I typically copy/paste its name in 4 different places!

- The declaration in the header file (`NSObject * myObject;`)
- The `@property()` line
- The `@synthesize()` line in the implementation
- Releasing it under `dealloc:` (only for objects of course)

I do this because it works, not because I completely understand what's going on. I do know that the declaration in the header file allows other classes to see its attributes, the property specifier determines how its getter/setter methods will be constructed. And the synthesize line actually builds those getter/setter methods. I also know that primitive types should use (`nonatomic,assign`) instead of (`nonatomic,retain`), but I have no clue when I should omit the nonatomic.

What can I do to avoid redundancy in my code. If I change or add a variable in my class I have to check 4 different places, and it gets old really fast. Are there any key strokes to make this process faster? Are there lines of code I can simplify or combine to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) will automate a lot of this for you.

Comment: Looks like a useful tool, I may look into it in the future when I do some Objective-C development of my own.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Clang (Ships with XCode 4, not in XCode 3 yet) you get default @synthesize as well as default ivar creation. The default ivar creation already works, but not on the simulator. With both of these features all you need to do is add the @property line and deal with the memory management in `dealloc`

As far as nonatomic vs atomic. atomic is the default, and what happens when you leave off the nonatomic annotation. Atomic guarantees that the value is completely set before allowing anything to access it, nonatomic doesn't. Atomic is only useful in threading situations, and is slightly slower in singlethreaded applications.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't yet have access to XCode 4. I'm looking forward to it though.

Comment: This also works with Xcode 3.2.4. Set your compiler to LLVM 1.5 and add `-Xclang` and `-fobjc-nonfragile-abi2` to your "Other C flags". If you do this, you can just declare the property (no ivar and no `@synthesize` needed) and access it through the setter and getter. AFAIK there is another workaround needed to access the auto-generated ivar (which I don't remember) but I find this is usually not necessary.

Comment: It also works in the Simulator. I am using this technique with several projects.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds scary to me. I'm just working part-time on this project and it is almost done, so it doesn't seem worth the risk of breaking low-level stuff. But thanks for the input Ole Begemann.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand what each of those lines of code does.  They are not all the same and they are **not** necessarily redundant.  One thing that will help is to use the correct terminology — for example, with `NSObject *myObject;` you're probably referring to an instance variable declaration.

First and foremost, a `@property` declaration in an `@interface` lets you say that instances of a class expose a piece of state.  It doesn't say much about the *implementation* of that state, only that it's exposed by instances of your class and the API contract (memory management, atomicity, methods) for the state.

The `@synthesize` directive tells the compiler to create or use a specific instance variable as storage for a declared `@property`.  *This does not need to be how you provide storage for a property.*  For example, Core Data provides its own storage for modeled properties, so you use `@dynamic` for those instead.  You also don't need to use an instance variable with the same name as your `@property` — to extend your example above, you might name your instance variable `myObject_` while naming your property `object` and that's perfectly fine.

Finally, you send the instance variable `-release` in `-dealloc` — for an object-type property marked `retain` or `copy` — because you've said you'll manage its memory.  You're not releasing the *property*, you're releasing the *storage*.  If you implemented the storage some other way, you'd clean it up some other way.